# Cannot drop Oracle linked server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to drop an oracle linked server in SQL Server 2014. However, the following statement

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LinkedSvr1', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_dropserver @server=N'LinkedSvr1', @droplogins='droplogins'
```

returns

```
Msg 20582, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSrepl_check_server, Line 34
Cannot drop server 'LinkedSvr1' because it is used as a Publisher in replication.
```

**Update:**
I dropped the linked server after run `exec sp_dropdistpublisher '...'`. However, it displayed the error

```
Msg 21749, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_dropdistpublisher, Line 337
The Publisher was dropped at the Distributor, but information on the Publisher '....' was not dropped. Connect to the Oracle Publisher with SQL*PLUS and drop the replication administrative user.
```

Answer (score 1):

`@optname=N'dist'` is the option to enable or disable a Distributor. As per the error message, this server is a Publisher, so try this instead:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LinkedSvr1', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
```

Comment: I ran the statement on the linked server but I still got the same error.